# Offset Largest Number in Selected Range

Tags: excel, vba

I want my function to select a range as a input. Then to find the top 5 number of the range. After we have the top 5 numbers I need the function to select the number below it. My VBA function can only find the top 5 numbers. I don't know why any of the code is not working. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

```
Function Getnum(row) As Integer
Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim firstVal As Double, secondVal As Double, thirdVal As Double, fourthVal As Double

Set Rng = row
Range("row").Select
Rng("row").Select

firstVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Rng, 1)
'Rng("firstVal").Select
'Ret1 = Rng("firstVal").Offset(4, 0).Select
'Range("firstVal").Select
'Ret1 = Range("firstVal").Offset(4, 0).Select
'ActivatefirstVal =
'strMyValue = ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Value
'Ret1 = ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).cell("firstVal")

'secondVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Rng, 2)
'thirdVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Rng, 3)
'fourthVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Rng, 4)

MsgBox "First Highest Value is " & firstVal
'MsgBox "Second Highest Value is " & secondVal
'MsgBox "Third Highest Value is " & thirdVal
'MsgBox "Fourth Highest Value is " & fourthVal
MsgBox "First Highest Ret " & Ret1

End Function
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248)